# Cannot export theme settings to the .info file

Tags: 7, drush

I am using Drupal 7. After modifying a setting for my theme in the Appearance menu, I get the following alert message on my site's homepage:

```
The settings for this theme are currently served from a variable. You might want to export them to your .info file. This is optional and can be done the Drush command 'drush omega-export'.
```

However, when I try to run the `drush omega-export` command, it fails:

```
$ drush omega-export
The drush command 'omega-export' could not be found.  Run `drush           [error]
cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed
new extensions.
A Drupal installation directory could not be found                         [error]
```

This happens even if I run as root. I ran the `drush cache-clear drush` command successfully, but that unfortunately did not fix the issue. How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Drush are you using?

Comment: The command `drush --version` outputs "drush version 5.9"

Answer (score 2):

The "omega" theme is the base theme for my theme. It needed to be Enabled, but not set as the default. After enabling the theme, the `drush omega-export` command worked successfully.